# Waze Applications for Developers - How to

Tags: javascript, testing, developer-tools, waze

Where can I test possible feature improvements for the Waze Application? Looking for a non-prod environment specifically. I've done some research where I found conversations from other developers mentioning testing...looks like an API existed at one point but no longer does for developers - https://www.waze.com/about/dev. Does anyone know if there is a live dev environment provided by Waze currently?

Comment: you may need to go through https://developers.google.com/waze

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the resources have moved to https://developers.google.com/waze/